# route on inner or outer layers for SPI clocks signals etc?

Tags: pcb-design, signal-processing, pcb-layers, signal-integrity

What is better for (for example) an SPI clock signal: to be routed on the inner layers (more ground, avoid EMC issue) or on the outer layer? (Avoid changing layers and impedance mismatch and any signal issue that can arise from that).

If you have to route some signals on the inner layer then what signals are best to choose for the inner layers? Clock signals? UART? I2C? Reset signals? PWM signals? Fast signals or slow?

Is it generally better to route signals on inner or outer layers? or it depends? and on what?

In my case, it is for a 6-layer PCBA with a BGA.

Comment: EMC is a holistic issue. We need to know everything about your board, and project requirements (emissions, shielding, attached wiring, etc.), before a clear conclusion can be drawn. At best we can only hand-wave, and that's a very dubious thing to give without such context.

Answer (score 1):

I'd say put least important generic signals to inner layers if necessary.

It's not so much what the signals are (UART, I2C, clock, reset or PWM) but what properties they require from the transmission line you provide with the PCB.

So yeah, it depends. On many factors.

First of all, if you have a 4-layer board, top and bottom are for important signals and two middle layers are mainly for ground and supply. As you have a BGA it may require 6 layers just to fan out the connections from it, while still providing good low impdance ground and supply voltage connectiond to it, even multiple supplies.

In general a 6 layer PCB has important high speed and impedance matched signas on top and bottom layers while layers 2 and 5 are the ground planes for these signals. This leaves layers 3 and 4 to supplies and random generic signals that do not need any special properties.

It depends what signals you have, what speed they run at, how fast transitions the signals have, how long the tracks are and if anything special is required such as specific track impedance, or impedance matching at source, or termination at the end.

Then, it depends on the stack-up or th composition of the PCB. You might have layers 1&2 and 5&6 very close to each other, and there might be more space between layers 2&3 and 4&5. In any case signals on layer 3 has capacitance to both layers 2 and 4 while layer 1 only has capacitance to layer 2. And thus impedance calculation is harder as there may be larger tolerances in manufacturing in the middle layers.

Which means that signals that don't allow much capacitive load or capacitive coupling to nearby signals should be placed in a layer where it has least capacitance to ground or other signals.

So without knowing anything about your signals or their properties it's hard to say what to do. In the end, they all are just logic level signals, some with faster signals than others, some requiring faster edges than others, some being push-pull type and some open-drain or open-collector.

Even if you have a slow signal, it may require fast edges, so it counts as a fast signal.

Comment: Thank you for your answer.  I noticed you did not mention so much about EMC. My understanding is that in the inner layer, the signals are more protected for immunity and emissions. is this the case?     for example a reset signal might fit the spec for something that should go on the inner layers?

Comment: @mrdude Well are there any requirements then? Sure if you put a signal between ground layers it won't radiate much or get disturbed much, but will it ever be a problem? A signal on top/bottom layer with ground layer right behind it should do almost as good job. If not, you add series terminating resistors to slow down signals, or you can add capacitors to signals to reduce their slew rate and it also absorbs more external disturbance. Or you add ferrite beads for RF filtering external interfaces. It would really fill a book to answer everything in detail and these books exist.

Comment: @mrdude And it depends on what resets you talk about. Many MCUs say there must be a capacitor on reset pin, and it can be very slow signal, as it is most often needed once when you power up the board, or at most every time an user pushes a reset button, or some in-system programmer or debugger is used to upload firmware to MCU.

Comment: OK, thank you very much for your input. One last question:   "signals on top and bottom layers while layers 2 and 5 are the ground planes for these signals." So were does the power go according to your opinion if one does a 6-layer board?   (I am doing a BGA board with DDR3 and BGA on top layer).  One entire layer for power? or just some polygon for power on some layer?  if polygon on what layer?

Comment: @mrdude Like I mentioned, you can use 3 and 4 for power. But these are not hard rules as you must do whatever you need to do to get the PCB routed with 6 layers. There likely is a howto from some manufacturer how a DDR3 bus shouls be routed. Maybe a bit late to add info about DDR3 at this point, it might be the most important thing you need to route properly, and evrything else is secondary as they are just random logic level signals.